# Can't run application from .cshtml tab

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Strange problem I got here. I using Visual Studio 2012. When I start debugging my web application from `.cshtml` tabs I getting this error

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Views/Header/GeneralInputs.cshtml
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225

When I run it from `.cs` tabs everything is fine and runs well. Whats wrong?

Here's my `RouteConfig`

```
  public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Header", action = "GeneralInputs", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Also I tried to adding this line into the `WebConfig`, but that didn't help

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

UPD:

what I got in
`HeaderController`

```
 public ActionResult GeneralInputs()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Go to Project properties, Web and select (o) Specific Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are seeing can actually be quite useful: directly run the page (Controller/Action) your cursor is in.

But when you frequently call this from a View, or from Actions that require parameters, you can fix your starting point from Project|Properties|Web, and then check the `(o) Specific Page` option.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't request this page like this:Requested URL`/Views/Header/GeneralInputs.cshtml`. You should request `Header/GeneralInputs`. You must request the Action in the controller. No the view in the controller

Comment: `You should request Header/GeneralInputs`

oh yeah, you right! 
so I need redirect to that URL in my `GeneralInputs` controller function?

Comment: In your controller, I presume you have an Action with `GeneralInputs` name and in this action you must return a view wich is your .cshtml file

Comment: `I need redirect to that URL`
well, acutally it didn't help

Comment: I change `return View();` to  `return Redirect("Header/GeneralInputs");` but it didn't help

Comment: then you should use `RedirectToAction("GeneralInputs");`

Answer (score 0):

The action name **"GeneralInputs"** should be in your **HeaderController** and **GeneralInputs.cshtml** file should be in **Header** View folder. if both are well and good. Then don't run your application while the cursor in **GeneralInputs.cshtml** page. Keep the cursor in the controller then run your application.

Comment: Well, both are well and good. But I wondering why I can't run it when cursour in the `.cshtml` page. I know I can run it from the controller but, however